# TextBlock content becomes invisible when TreeViewItem Header is selected

Tags: wpf

Included below is the source to a simple WPF application which uses a `TreeView`. Here's what it looks like when run:

[image]

Note however that if I click on one of the `TreeViewItem` headers:

[image]

the text in the `TreeViewItem` is no longer visible.

What's a good way to fix this so that the text remains visible when the header is selected?

As you can see, the code is primarily in C# so C#-based answers are preferred, but XAML is welcome too; I'll just convert it to C#.

---

**UPDATE**

If I set the `Foreground` of the `TextBlock` explitly to `Black` as suggested in an answer below:

```
{
    var tree_view_item = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "abc" };

    tree_view_item.Items.Add(new ScrollViewer() { Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "123", Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black) } });

    tree_view.Items.Add(tree_view_item);
}
```

it does indeed appear to help:

[image]

However, if I then select the `TextBlock`, the textblock is shown as black on blue which is a little awkward:

[image]

Is there a way to also change the background color used when the item is highlighted?

---

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewItemHighlightColor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeViewItemHighlightColor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TreeViewItemHighlightColor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var tree_view = new TreeView();

            {
                var tree_view_item = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "abc" };

                tree_view_item.Items.Add(new ScrollViewer() { Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "123" } });

                tree_view.Items.Add(tree_view_item);
            }

            {
                var tree_view_item = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "bcd" };

                tree_view_item.Items.Add(new ScrollViewer() { Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "234" } });

                tree_view.Items.Add(tree_view_item);
            }

            {
                var tree_view_item = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "cde" };

                tree_view_item.Items.Add(new ScrollViewer() { Content = new TextBlock() { Text = "345" } });

                tree_view.Items.Add(tree_view_item);
            }

            Content = tree_view;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting it like that will stop it turning white when selected. Because set values have precedence over all else. You could try setting it via a style instead. I don't follow why there's a scrollviewer there. I also suggest looking into templating and binding generally. If you're going to do much wpf then you want to learn mvvm.

Comment: @Andy I included the `ScrollViewer` because this example is based on an actual program which uses `ScrollViewer` elements in that place.

Answer (score 1):

There's a chance that the `Foreground` property of the `TextBlock` is being inherited and altered by the state of the `TreeViewItem`.

Set the `Foreground` property of the `TextBlock` to black. That way, the TreeViewItem will not override it.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my answer to acknowledge that this does indeed fix the issue! It brings up another issue however. :-)

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, you might need to rethink the UI Logic. You'll probably need to read more about Templating in XAML.
I would create a template for the TreeViewItem which wraps the ContentPresenter of the TreeViewItem inside a ScrollViewer, and then, instead of adding TextBlocks to a TreeViewItem and then it to the TreeView, add the strings directly to the TreeView. It will attempt to present your string using the TreeViewItem template.